# Output folder for compiled TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

I'm following a tutorial called THE HERO EDITOR, and it has me creating and editing TypeScript files in an `app` folder. The app uses a script `tsc -w`, where the `w` causes the `tsc` transpiler to output a new JavaScript file every time a TypeScript file fails.

This caused me some confusion for several minutes, because when I added a TypeScript class, the editor (Visual Studio Code) underlined the class name and told me it was a duplicate declaration. I saw the JavaScript file with the same name, but no sooner had I deleted it, the duplicate declaration, and thus the JS file, were back.

The script is declared in `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
},
```

Where can I specify where compiled JavaScript goes? I doubt I can do it here, but I can only guess that I need a `grunt` or equivalent file, but then what do I do in that file, and do I remove the `tsc` entries from `package.js' once another file takes over?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

We can control where our compiled javascript goes with the help of `"outDir`" parameter of `"compilerOptions"` in our `tsconfig.json` file.

I am also using Visual Studio Code and I generally create my `tsconfig.json` file at the project root directory. Here is an example, where I want my compiled javascript to go inside `"src/ts-out/"` directory

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "src/ts-out/"
    }    
}
```

Hope it helps. Happy coding...

Comment: Use `tsc --init` to create a default `tsconfig.json` file

Answer (score -4):

As far as i know, the compiled ts files are saved in the same folder as the ts files.

Comment: By default, yes, but I'm nearly certain there is a way to specify a destination folder.

Comment: There are `--outDir` and `--outFile` options for the `tsc` command line, but I have not had chance to test them properly. When I didn't use the command line but `tsconfig.json`, as `"outDir": "./TestOut"`, it didn't make a difference. The options are listed here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Comment: @ProfK `"outDir:` should be in `"compilerOptions"` in `tsconfig.json`.